# Assign the same field in an array of classes

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of a class called Book with three fields, **int** pYear, **String** name and **String** author. Now I want to initialize all of the pYear in the array. Is there a faster way to do this than:

```
bList[0].pYear=1996;
bList[1].pYear=1998;
bList[2].pYear=2000;
```

and so on?

Comment: Where are the values stored?

Comment: I want to assign them manually right now, so basically nowhere. Should I first store them in an array of integers?

Comment: How do you create `Book` objects for `bList` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "faster" you mean typing less code, you can do something like this :

```
int[] years = {1996,1998,2000,...};
for (int i = 0; i < years.length && i < bList.length; i++)
    bList[i].pYear = years[i];
```

Of course it would be better to make `pYear` private and use a setter method instead of direct assignment.

In java 8 you can reduce it to two lines :

```
int[] years = {1996,1998,2000,...};
IntStream.range(0,bList.length).forEach(i->bList[i].pYear = years[i]);
```

Comment: This was nice, but it is basically the same method. I wonder if there is a way to do that like the first line of your code. Anyways, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific Object (class) with multiple fields, it's probably bad design (but not unnacceptable design, specially if this is an assignment) to initialize it in a per-field basis rather than per-object.

If there are many objects, you can create a simple json or xml file with the books' fields' data, and create a simple loader with `BufferedReader` that creates a `List<Book>` for you with `new Book(year, name, author);`, and that you can convert to array if needed.